# John Resig's perf function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, unit-testing

I want to test the performance of my js code and I am looking for `perf` function that John Resig has in his book ["Secrets of Javascript Ninja"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398869X). Does anyone know about how to create such function or **simple function** (same as John's `perf`) ***instead of using a testing library***?

Here is how his function works:

```
perf('my test', function(){
   // code to test for performance
})
```

I could not find it on google or book's code.

Comment: Not quite what you're asking, but there's a website where you can test JS performance: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Have you read Chapter Two of the book?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Yes i have but it uses that function i want to get that function for my personal use, don't know how he has written that.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I want to have same function as john's `perf` for testing my code rather than importing a testing lib. I just need a simple function like that of john to test performance of my js code.

Comment: @Dev555 Take a look inside of Michael's function. You'll find there all what you need. That is: at your function start, define a Date, when finished define a new Date and calculate the difference between those two Dates. The result is not accurate, because CPU is working outside of your script almost all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many simple benchmarking patterns described in an article titled [Bulletproof JavaScript benchmarks](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/bulletproof-javascript-benchmarks/) by Mathias Bynens and John-David Dalton. It's a good read.

Also for those interested or looking for more then a simple test suite unlike OP, here's a few:

- http://benchmarkjs.com/ (is what jsPerf uses, also started by Mathias Bynens and John-David Dalton)
- http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/ or https://github.com/broofa/jslitmus
- https://github.com/jeresig/dromaeo (created by John Resig)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the book and don't know what exactly is meant here, but something similar to python's timeit might look like this:

```
perf = function(fn) {
    var times = 1000;
    if (parseInt(arguments[0]) > 0) {
        times = parseInt(arguments[0]);
        fn = arguments[1];
    }
    var d = new Date();
    while (times--) fn();
    return new Date() - d;
}
```

Usage: perf(myFunc) or perf(5000, myFunc)

Comment: I tried that but browser get hung. Can you show an example of how to use it for example on jsfiddle or jsbin? Thanks

Comment: works for me. Try lower the default `times` value, maybe 1000 is too much.